# Can ssh-keygen be seeded to generate the same key?

Tags: ssh, security

Is it possible to seed `ssh-keygen` with a fixed string so that it consistently generates the same keypair?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can't you copy the key files instead?

Comment: @SvenW I can, and I am, but this would be an alternative for when there is no central repository to store the keys.

Comment: And why is this downvoted? I can understand if one does not agree with  this method, but this is not a bad question?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom if you lack a central repository to store the keys then you also lack a central repostory to store the seeds, no?

Comment: This is a valid question. The seeds could be generated from a condition, like a hostname or MAC address. If the public key has been put in authorized_keys on other servers, if the machine is rebuilt for any reason, the key can be regenerated from the hostname (without keys having to be stored somewhere), and it will retain access to those other servers. I'd also be interested in an answer to how this may be done.

Comment: If you could, then the tool - and your keys - would be useless.

Comment: I think this makes sense - maybe not in production, but if I want to use ssh-keygen for benchmarking it is very nice if it could be made to perform the same execution each time.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can pick certain criteria which *may* reduce the randomness of the generated key, but the generation process is not a simple as picking a particular seed from which the keys are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just not with the default ssh-keygen. I personally use [ssh-key-generator](https://github.com/mithrandi/ssh-key-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another cool tool for generating deterministic ssh keys: [cornfeedhobo/ssh-keydgen](https://github.com/cornfeedhobo/ssh-keydgen), it's written on go